# Selenium explicit wait not working in new safariDriver 2.48.0

Tags: python, selenium, safaridriver

Explicit waits in my codes are not working in SafariDriver 2.48.0. it's working in chrome in windows and MAC. when wait is reached it's driver throwing exception

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 71, in until
>       value = method(self._driver)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 78, in **call**
>       return _element_if_visible(_find_element(driver, self.locator))
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/expected_conditions.py", line 98, in _element_if_visible
>       return element if element.is_displayed() == visibility else False
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 358, in is_displayed
>       return self._execute(Command.IS_ELEMENT_DISPLAYED)['value']
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 494, in _execute
>       return self._parent.execute(command, params)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 163, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(value)

My code is:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
self.driver.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60)
self.driver.get("http://example.com")
# Click Sign in button and wait for sign in page
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(XMLDict['SignIn'].Xpath).click()
self.driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, XMLDict['User'].ID)))
self.driver.maximize_window()
```

Configuration:

```
OS - macOS Sierra
Selenium 3.0.1
Safari - 10.0.1
SafariDriver - 2.48.0
Python 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Xpath doesn't work well with Safari, try to solve your problem with CSS_SELECTOR, ID, or CLASS_NAME